# Gedit PHP syntax highlighting

Tags: php, gedit, syntax-highlighting

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? I have PHP inline to HTML. There's an opening quotation and the inline PHP also has a quote, but Gedit thinks it's the closing quote for the HTML.

Add this to Gedit (would post a pic but I need 10 rep):

```
<div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse<?=$value["id"];?>" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

Answer (score 0):

It's fine in  gedit 3.20.2.

This maybe help you http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/06/install-gedit-3-10-ubuntu-16-04-lts